# What technologies were used to create NFS Most Wanted 2005

Tags: c++, 3d, game-engine, game-physics, game-theory

The black edition of most wanted was released in 2005 and I know they used C++ for programming the game. Say someone has a master knowledge of C++. He wants to create a game like NFS 2005. What tools he will need to start programming. What I know about NFS is that the game wasn't created using any pre-existing engine. May be I m wrong. But if not, then what they used for those graphics. Ignore the tracks. I just want to know what technologies were implemented for making the overall game perfect.

Comment: a) A game consists of more than a programming language. Graphics (the "creating" part, not "displaying"), music, story, level design, etc.etc., b) If the creators didn´t use some existing engine, they made their own. Look up what "game engine" means. c) If displaying graphics without engines isn´t possible, how do you think engines are made? d) This whole question shows that you need to google much more.

Comment: Lots of teamwork. The actual coding is but one part of these remarkable creations.

Comment: @deviantfan by saying "the game wasn't created using any engine", I mean they didn't use any preexisting game engine.

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal Then a part of what they made is their own engine. Making a big game in a way that no part can be separated from the rest and called "engine" is pretty much impossible (= everything is spaghetti code, including the bytes of the images etc.etc.)

Comment: Most Wanted was almost certainly developed using the studio's internal Need For Speed engine (which they had worked on for years) if they didn't use a third-party one. It's impossible to create games like this from scratch at the rate of one per year - you'd have to settle for one every decade or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

99% sure they used an engine. The engine is the main source to create a game such as NFS, a huge API with a variety of features. Use the Unreal engine if anything, as it is free currently. Graphics as well as code will be used there (Blueprint will mostly be used instead of code honestly).

Answer (score 0):

Everything used to make NFS MW was either inhouse, or EA-provided.
To be a little more specific, the graphics were powered by an inhouse library called EAGL (EA Graphics Library, which the studio developed and used), and the audio was mostly handled by an inhouse engine and partly by EA-provided libraries (namely, the music, copspeech, and NIS audio), with every version except the PC version using EAGL 3, with the PC version using a possibly modified version of EAGL 2, which is why so many particle effects present in other versions of the game are missing (the library literally doesn't even know what they are).